# Find all homomorphisms from $D_4$ to $\mathbb{Z}_4$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

My professor put this question on a practice test with a hint that there is more than one but less than five. 
$$D_4=\{I,R,R^2,R^3,F,RF,R^2F,R^3F\}$$

---

I started looking at the order of the elements in each group since I know that the order of an element $a\in D_4$ will have to divide $\phi(a)$. Together $R$ and $F$ will generate all of $D_4$, so knowing where those elements go should determine where all of the others go as well.

Unfortunately, I'm getting getting seven homomorphisms though (I haven't checked them all). Am I thinking about the problem the right way?

Comment: How did you come up with the seven homomorphisms you have? What are they?

Comment: Everything to 0. $(F\rightarrow 0, R\rightarrow 1)$,  $(F\rightarrow 0, R\rightarrow 2)$, $(F\rightarrow 0, R\rightarrow 3)$,  $(F\rightarrow 1, R\rightarrow 0)$,  $(F\rightarrow 1, R\rightarrow 1)$, $(F\rightarrow 1, R\rightarrow 2)$,  $(F\rightarrow 1, R\rightarrow 3)$. There were 8 actually.

Comment: The answers below should sort this out for you.

Answer (score 3):

The images of $R$ and $F$ in $\mathbb Z_4$ need to satisfy the relations that $R$ and $F$ satisfy in $D_4$, so $R^4 = F^2 = 1$ and $RFR = F$.  As $\mathbb Z_4$ is commutative (and usually written additively), that last relation between the images $\phi(R)$ and $\phi(F)$ becomes $\phi(R) + \phi(F) + \phi(R) = \phi(F)$ or $2\phi(R) = 0$.  This is probably the relation you've forgotten to take into account.

In all you need $\phi(F)$ and $\phi(R)$ to satisfy $2\phi(F) = 2\phi(R) = 0$ so there are $2$ choices for each giving $4$ total.

Answer (score 2):

$R$ has order $4$, so it can be mapped to anything just by considering the order. $F$ has order $2$, so it has to be mapped to $0$ or $2$.

If $D_4$ is the dihedral group, you will also have $RF = FR^3$. Since $\mathbb Z_4$ is abelian, $R$ and $R^3$ must be mapped to the same thing. That makes $1$ and $3$ impossible choices for $R$. Therefore, $R$ must be mapped to $0$ or $2$, and $F$ must be mapped to $0$ or $2$. There are 4 possibilities in total.

Comment: You are right. I'll edit it :P